# Autohotkey to resize window with child windows

Tags: resize, parent-child, autohotkey, mdichild, frontpage

I use FrontPage 2003 for linking html files, through the command 'Insert' > Hyperlink.

And the window opens as follows:
[image]

I made a script with Autohotkey to resize the window, so I see more of the files in the 'current folder' (I think the class is SysTreeView32), but it doesn't apply to the child windows (I guess it is called mdichild), it shows as follows:
[image]

What I need is to make the script resizes the window and all the child windows.

The current scrip is:

```
#NoEnv

ResizeWin(Width = 0,Height = 0)
{
  WinGetPos,X,Y,W,H,A
  If %Width% = 0
    Width := W

  If %Height% = 0
    Height := H

  WinMove,A,,%X%,%Y%,%Width%,%Height%
}

#!u::ResizeWin(800,800)
```

Comment: What end-goal are you trying to accomplish in making the window bigger? To easily select a larger number of elements? Or just navigate faster? If the latter, then I may be able to suggest another approach to solving your problem.

Comment: yes I just need to see more files to select from, other than those 10 folders/files showing..

Comment: Instead of resizing the actual dialog, you could also consider intercepting the original window, and pop up a custom GUI dialog with your script; after a file has been chosen, you can feed it to the original dialog. Maybe a little more effort, but at least it would work.

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshot, it looks like the resize is working.

Unfortunately, there are some windows that just don't resize properly. I assume that if you use your mouse, you can't resize it manually either. This is especially prevalent for older programs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of resizing individual *controls*, would be to use the [ControlMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlMove.htm) command.

However, in order to use this command, the control must be able to be detected.  This would be either as ClassNN, control name, or HWND (window handle).